# Why is my domain's email forwarding working really strangely?

Tags: php, email, forwarding

This is a maddening problem that makes absolutely no sense to me, so I'm going to see if I can spell it out step by step and at least figure out WHERE the problem is.

1. I have a PHP form that sends an email to **godaddy email**
   The code reads: `$email_to = "admin@amvleague.com";`
2. My domain is currently set up to forward emails from **godaddy email** to **old Gmail**.
3. Currently, everything works perfectly.  Mails sent to **godaddy email** from this form end up in **old Gmail**
4. I am trying to retire **old Gmail** and set up a new email, **new Gmail**
5. I go into my webhosting for my domain and change the forwarding for **godaddy email** from **old Gmail** to **new Gmail**
6. I send an email from anywhere to **godaddy email**.  The email arrives in **new Gmail** perfectly.
7. I go and test the PHP form.  I click submit, and *the email is forwarded to **old Gmail**!*
8. NOTHING has changed, and email from anywhere else BUT this form is sent just fine to **new Gmail.**  But the form continues to forward to **old Gmail**

Can...anyone figure out why?  Since email from anywhere else shows up to **new Gmail**, I don't think the problem is my hosting.  And since I haven't changed the PHP code at all, I don't see how it can be my code.  I'm completely stumped as to why this is happening.

I've taken one of the generated emails sent to **old Gmail** and opened the raw code.  Hopefully, this will help.

```
     Delivered-To: saintsmythe@gmail.com
Received: by 10.192.245.69 with SMTP id w5csp2043662imp;
        Mon, 16 Apr 2018 19:37:59 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AIpwx4/7IXFxsp77K2q5TVhEg9BWpnzoT6curENaIbXsQeNnlmP7E1RI+c6Ax+cCf/Ha221e+TYE
X-Received: by 10.101.81.131 with SMTP id h3mr263230pgq.110.1523932679630;
        Mon, 16 Apr 2018 19:37:59 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1523932679; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=PA8c4ZydbOZ87gc4cxOwDGj9r5c7qZcuiyu9wQLSDWIXcEDKCiyWUiU8hLVhXqjTjI
         vtxvJwnhd+2lfSUnmsD1+kTpuest59sfInI75CVKZWBb9QyTCWDrok/+jhmMq2dd6RGW
         uW19N4+h02Iey+SSk1uaL2c2gRQCSDmlXj1bPUz5fytKhc2ZlV5yTfYx1UFBijQ/DHxM
         sobAozj2qeYnaKUvQYHpCxSN7UeYcPYgys+dqqsgDZWC0NHI1dCisIO40JT3rqnuFflN
         LgxR0GLnZjNYZRyaAJdfwIUmSalSFOWvY2zVMrO2JBQWxPdIGg3hLpmvvJKgmf01oJUI
         z/PA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:reply-to:from:subject:to:arc-authentication-results;
        bh=Dc3kwa2Lw+kVdjs/17dWvdT/XG2vPpwHbeaBi1mZ9mI=;
        b=D4MYUF1NI/GXVSMPZBmJ3Up/tw/PZLber4WGJ0PDfPowtc+iyuMaGKUF5WkoYTdNdj
         DHFFWMJN9ZJW3DzLczagrcpYaDgcWt75QyQSDofutXHk6SgZ/wR5ExUQWMvnaytruDp6
         qhsoq4o7EuKJ+rB/Nz7CZ+mPgazoDJ2BlVb1BioqeraEz1+GzgP5NmodLyjOKMUVpaZP
         IZVU+q7iPFJyJVaGWQs0O+qkR34ETUp30p9KKJT4xdDQt45exA4yQKnmY5hQaOU39kn7
         m5EljXpnmpcw5O9CRopTAdhsUIVx6DQ2/X0izphUf3qAaCS5TYwb9G4YrfVRnxM4/6jr
         ONXA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of pathosprime@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net designates 184.168.200.138 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=pathosprime@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Return-Path: <pathosprime@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Received: from p3nlsmtpcp01-01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (p3nlsmtpcp01-01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net. [184.168.200.138])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id bg3-v6si12712825plb.118.2018.04.16.19.37.59
        for <saintsmythe@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Mon, 16 Apr 2018 19:37:59 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of pathosprime@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net designates 184.168.200.138 as permitted sender) client-ip=184.168.200.138;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of pathosprime@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net designates 184.168.200.138 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=pathosprime@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: from p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ([50.62.176.157]) by : HOSTING RELAY : with SMTP id 8GUMfAEwZhCGd8GUMflmtd; Mon, 16 Apr 2018 19:36:58 -0700
Received: from pathosprime by p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.89_1) (envelope-from <pathosprime@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>) id 1f8GUM-0006UO-Sh for pathos@vitaminh.info; Mon, 16 Apr 2018 19:36:58 -0700
To: pathos@vitaminh.info
Subject: San Japan 2018 - AMV League Submission
X-PHP-Script: vitaminh.info/formSubmit_sj2018.php for 75.17.243.59
From: kiddmaniac@gmail.com
Reply-To: kiddmaniac@gmail.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.45
Message-Id: <E1f8GUM-0006UO-Sh@p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 19:36:58 -0700
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - vitaminh.info
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [1301146 964] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net: authenticated_id: pathosprime/only user confirmed/virtual account not confirmed
X-Authenticated-Sender: p3plcpnl0702.prod.phx3.secureserver.net: pathosprime
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: /usr/sbin/proxyexec -q -d -s /var/lib/proxyexec/cagefs.sock/socket /bin/cagefs.server
X-Source-Dir: vitaminh.info:/public_html
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfJEf+sdDYOUnOmductCj6nBdQRWa/6wUgdoK6O2CAWe0PrjNSlBuLyI4Rfb552np9zNYxrtCHZ/hdqAWO6T7B+vC6JkwPqB4ugL4S1ZaPVNom+n0ZERQ Ee9QZ3jQQC6Bz6GtQ9pA+VU+MNx4Wl3XnSNvDDQJzdX6+bqR5/WHAGLAx0S+p1PcsHrpPsxkUfsPS0FN4epECxJq5BhtED8Ns3Lorom7oHGV0xJX9bmW/GK2 r8DgL2p+962yd8/9/QSo5A==
```

Comment: What do you mean by "old webmail" and "new webmail"? Which one is GoDaddy? You really need to [name all of the service providers](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632), and you might want to show the actual domain name as well (though I don't yet think that will be necessary, it may be helpful).

Comment: @Michael Hampton Ok, I've gone ahead and changed everything back to the original.  I really want to get this problem fixed.  I've tried to clarify everything in the original post, but if I put to many @ signs outside of code, serverfault flags it as spam and won't let me post.  Let me know if this helps.